# How is it possible to determine the order of a finite group G from a given subnormal chain for G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This was a task in a practice sheet for group theory.

The answer to the question is yes, but I'm oblivious as to how it is possible.

The subnormal chain would only give us a sequence of groups ${e} ... \le G_2 \le G_1 \le G$ such that each $G_{i+1}$ is normal to $G_i$. I don't see how this connects to the order of the group.

Perhaps $G_1 + [G:G_1] = G$? And similarly for each $G_i$? But this would be under the assumption that i know the index of $G_1$ in G.

Comment: I mean do you know what the groups are? If so, then just find the order of the last group.

Comment: I'm given only the subnormal chain, without G. The idea is to use the subnormal chain to deduce the order of G.

Comment: But $G$ is one part of a subnormal chain. Otherwise the question is impossible, because  $1\le \Bbb Z/(2)$ would be a truncated subnormal series for $\Bbb Z/(2p)$ for any odd prime $p$

Comment: Understood. But then what difference does it make if i have the subnormal chain of G? I just need G, no? Does the subnormal chain help me somehow?

Comment: Seems like it might just be a bit of a trick question, otherwise I'm not sure what the point is.

Comment: It seems that the question just wants you to understand the iterating process underlying a subnormal chain. This is a common tool to prove something about groups when the quotients $G_i/G_{i+1}$ are peculiar.
So your answer is correct : $|G|=|G/G_1|+|G_1|$. If $G/G_1$ is a nice group (as $Z/p$), $|G/G_1|$ is easy to know and you continue with the chain $G_1 \geqslant G_2 \geqslant \cdots$

Comment: If you don't have any information on the quotients $G/G_i$ (here the orders) you can't find the order of $G$

Comment: Understood Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given subnormal chain

$$e=G_n\trianglelefteq G_{n-1}\trianglelefteq\cdots\trianglelefteq G_1\trianglelefteq G_0=G$$

we can apply [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) (note: it should be multiplication instead of addition) inductively to obtain

$$|G|=|G_{n}/G_{n-1}|\cdot |G_{n-1}/G_{n-2}|\cdots |G_1/G_2|\cdot |G_0/G_1|$$

And so I assume that the author actually meant "determine the order of $G$ from orders of quotients in a subnormal series". Otherwise, as you've noted yourself, given a subnormal chain you already have $G$ and so this is trivial. In this setup it is not trivial, because quotients of a subnormal series do not determine $G$, e.g. consider $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. But they do determine $|G|$.

The result is analogous to how a number decomposes into product of prime numbers and we can improve it even further into [Jordan-Hölder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#Uniqueness:_Jordan%E2%80%93H%C3%B6lder_theorem).